# Disabling Wysyig profile profile for particular content type

Tags: wysiwyg, input-formats

I am using [CKeditor](https://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) with [wysiwyg](https://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) profile .
I want to disable this [Wysyig](https://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) profile for a particular content type.
cant find a better way.
please help me out with any module if its there or any configuration setting if its possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a similar issue and did it using [Better Formats](https://drupal.org/project/better_formats) module.

- I created a new Input Format (for example "my input format")
- Disabled WYSIWYG in that format
- In the Content type settings, under "Input format settings", select that new profile as default

Answer (score 0):

You could use plain text, (or create a text format called "No WYSIWYG" if you plan to support tags (*/admin/config/content/formats*) and set that profile in CKEditor as inactive (*/admin/config/ckeditor*).

Then just change the format for your content type to plain text or "No WYSIWYG"(*admin/structure/types/*).